# Links from internet explorer 11 not working in edge

Tags: internet-explorer, reporting-services, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

In reporting services I have reports which contains links to attachments:

-When i using IE11 and clicking links everything is working fine

-but when i do the same in edge we have no reaction, when we clicking open in new tab, We only see error about:blank#blocked

-when we export reports to excel and click link, everything is working fine too

links to attachments looks like file://servername/folder/folder/attachments.xls

any ideas how to solve that problem ?

Comment: There are lots of posts about this. All common new browsers (Chrome, Edge etc) no longer support opening network files from hyperlinks.

Comment: i know that, but is any workaround for this ?

Comment: Not that I know of otherwise I would have actually posted an answer. If you read all the threads on the topic there does not seem to be a way round it.

Comment: If it is a file in the intranet area, you can try to set it through [IntranetFileLinksEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#intranetfilelinksenabled) policy. Otherwise, as already mentioned, modern browsers do not support it due to security issues.

Answer (score 0):

Change the links in your site to "**ms-excel:ofv|u|file:///NameOfServer/NameOfFolder/mytest.csv**" instead of "**file://NameOfServer/NameOfFolder/mytest.csv**".  Taken from https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2261689-how-to-open-a-local-shared-file-in-chromium-edge.